# VB script with sql insert. Conversion of a varchar data type to DateTime

Tags: sql, vbscript, datetime-conversion

The current info needs to be handled:

```
Tid:            13.12.2014 01:48:48
```

what the script contains handling this is:

```
if isArray (arrString) then
  if uBound (arrString) > 0 then
    Select Case lcase (arrString(0))
      Case "tid": tid = trim (arrString (1)) & ":" & trim (arrString (2)) & ":" & trim (arrString (3))
```

When inserting with this code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO LoginLogg VALUES ('" & tiden & "', '" & brukernavn & "', '" & maskinnavn & "', '" & operativsystem & "', '" & servicepack & "', '" & minne & "', '" & produsent & "', '" & modell & "', '" & bios & " / "  & bios2 & "', '"& serienummer & "', '"& printere & "', '"& ipadresse & "', '"& imagedato & "', '" & opplosninger & "')"
```

This into SQL it returns:

> the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
>       errorcode: 80040e07

I cant find the reason why it wont work now. The database was moved from a 2003 to a 2008 R2.

If this would have been powershell i would have been able to solve this but VB isnt my strongest suit.

Updated the title hoping it is more suiting, along with the sql insertion code.

Comment: Administer (and provide into sql) date and time in language / culture / locale indifferent [ISO format](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) using next template:  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fix the discrepancy between `tid` and `tiden`
2. See if feeding a m/d/y **string** - `trim (arrString (2)) & "/" & trim (arrString (1)) & "/" & trim (arrString (3))` 'works'
3. If (2) fails or you don't want a hack, try to concat a date **literal** "#m/d/y#" into your SQL statement
4. If (3) fails or you want to do it correctly, use an ADODB.Command/prepared statement with a **date** parameter - obtained by [DateSerial()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1we4t8hy%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) on CInt(arrString(...))

Comment: Hi
I used tiden = Replace(tid,".","/")  to fix the the / or - between the dates but still it fails on sql insert.

I will see if i can google your advices

Comment: @vya - did you change the order (m/d/y) in proposal (2)?

Comment: Cdate  doesnt convert it as here i norway the order of writing is as it is allready.

The secondary solution you suggested returns:
48/13.12.2014 01/58

Comment: @vya - CDate isn't relevant here, because the conversion fails at the server. The result `48/13.12.2014 01/58` shows that your arrString doesn't contain what is to be expected, publish the array and the resulting tid[en]. Test if hardcoding `12/13/2014 01:48:48 AM` or `#12/13/2014 01:48:48 AM#` into your SQL statement works, if yes, adapt your string building accordingly. All this rigmarole could be avoided by approach (4).

Answer (score 0):

So i tried hardcoding the format that sql normally accepts: 2014/01/24 22:00:00
This failed.

then i tried to learn to split the strings with vb and joining them by doing:

```
Dim ArrSpace, ArrDot

ArrSpace = Split(tid, " ")
ArrDot = Split(ArrSpace(0), ".")
tid = ArrDot(2) & "/" & ArrDot(1) & "/" & ArrDot(0) & " " & ArrSpace(1)
```

Then inserting tid. this worked now :) thank you for guiding me in the correct direction.

Thank you Ekkehard.Homer